# Bootstrap 4 and Parsley not validating custom or normal radio buttons

Tags: bootstrap-4, parsley.js

Developing a Bootstrap 4 site and using Parsley to validate a form. Text fields and select drop downs are successfully being validated but the radio buttons are not.

```
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" required>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Do you live in Northern Ireland?</label>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ireland" id="ireland1" value="yes" required>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="ireland1">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ireland" id="ireland2" value="no">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="ireland2">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
    $("#personal").parsley({
       errorClass: 'is-invalid',
       errorsWrapper: '<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>',
       errorTemplate: '<span></span>',
       trigger: 'change'
    });
</script>
```

I think Parsley is attempting to add the invalid-feedback div in the wrong location for radio groups. Any advice would be appreciated as I am new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding a separate container around the radio inputs so it looks like:

```
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label>Do you live in Northern Ireland?</label>
        <div id="error-container">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ireland" id="ireland1" value="yes" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container" required>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="ireland1">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ireland" id="ireland2" value="no" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="ireland2">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem with this solution is that I need to create a unique id for each radio group.

Comment: That works. `data-parsley-errors-container` can be a function, so you could do it programatically.